# Maps faster than normal arrays?

Tags: arrays, maps

Do maps with `char-type keys` have faster access time than `normal arrays`?

The reason I think this is true is because normal arrays have `integer-type indexing` while the maps I think about have `char-type indexing`.

Integers are **4 bytes** while chars are only **1 byte**, so it seems reasonable to believe that accessing a map item at a given char key is faster than accessing a normal array item at a given integer index. In other words, the CPU has fewer bytes of the index/key value to examine to determine which element in the array is being referred to in memory.

Comment: a) no, its not a reasonable to assume that indexing with bytes is faster than indexing with ints (microbenchmarks pending) b) how would the map be implemented in the first place? Using arrays?

Comment: a) I think you confused your terminology. b) As far as I know, a map is basically an array since it's a list of indexed items. The only thing that matters apart from the index type is that the normal arrays and the char-type-keyed maps have the same content type (e.g. an array of ints has int as its content type). If we assume C++, I would use an unordered map. Use the fastest map type for whatever programming language you're using.

Comment: I would recommend you to read a bit more on a difference between associative arrays (maps) and directly addressed arrays and then rephrase the question.

Comment: std::unordered_map is a hash table, which will obviously be slower than a normal array, because its implementation is much more involved. Array access is simply a multiply+add+memory fetch operation, and CPUs are very fast in doing that. For a hash table, you will need to compute the hash value, look up the entries in the hash buckets and compare the keys (of course, it depends on the particular implementation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maps are slower than Arrays.
Because, Maps are actually implementation of arrays.
But for larger amount of data, you can use HashMap since you get rid of comparisons (if used correctly).

Comment: So the normal array is basically the fastest list of items in any high-level programming language?

Comment: @MånsNilsson I am very much tempted to answer yes (provided your language implements a directly addressed array), but the reality is more complicated. If we are talking about 'retrieve the element with the index i', where the indexes are continuous integer numbers, then yes, you can't really get any faster than a directly addressed array. If we add deletion/insertion/search or sparse containers into the mix, the answer will be different. Associative arrays and other data structures exist exactly because 'normal' arrays are less optimal in many usage scenarios.

Comment: Does that mean map items are slower to retrieve? E.g. say that we have the int map "tesst" with three integers, mapped to key values 'a', 'f' and 'x' respectively, and the normal int array "default" with three elements, all three of which are initialized. Is tesst['f'] then a faster operation/command than default[1]?